# Showing tooltip on asp.net MS chart controls

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Asp.net chart controls in order to display charts. I have a datatable which I'm directly binding to the control like this:

```
Chart1.DataSource = dtChart;
Chart1.DataBind();
```

Now, I would like to know how I can display a tooltip when mouse is hovered over each data points in the chart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the tooltip in the Series like so:

```
<Series>
    <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="SeriesName" ToolTip="Value of X: #VALX Value of Y #VALY" >
    </asp:Series>
</Series>
```

This will show the values of the X and Y point when you mouse over it.

Comment: "Value of X" should be `#VALX` and not `#VALY`, but otherwise this works great.